# Post to secret group using graph api of facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Graph API Explorer for testing purpose. I get a token with :

user_mananged_groups and publish_actions

When I try to post to one of my **secret** group, I get

```
(#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer
```

I am using this call: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed#publish.  Is it possible through the explorer to POST things?

I can get the posts of my secret group with GET.

Do I need an App(facebook app) to be able to make calls and post on my secret group?

Comment: Yes, you need an App to do any call to Facebook but if what you want is just testing the Graph API you can use the Graph Explorer, which is another App. You can use GET, POST and PUT in the Graph Explorer. Not sure why you're getting that error, if the owner of the access token is also admin of the secret group, I think you should be able to POST.

Answer (score 0):

I've got that error and I could fix it giving correct permission to application from facebook settings account. There you choose apps tab and look for your application, then you give access that your posts was visible to friends or public at least. Then try and look if you don't get the error anymore.

Regards

Comment: This should be a comment